# How to: Drag and Drop movement in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop, windows-store-apps

I wanted to make a simple matching game to help get a better understanding of movement, in which I would have the outline of a shape and the shape itself.  Drag the shape over its outline and release it to have it snap into place.  It Sounded simple.  I am able to move my shapes using the ManipulationDelta events but some reason I am unable to get any of the Drag Events to fire (DragOver, DragEnter, Drop).  I have read up on these events but perhaps my understanding is flawed.  What event am I looking for in order to know when one shape is dragged over another?

XAML

```
<Canvas Name="DrawCanvas">
    <Ellipse Name="Shape1" Fill="SteelBlue" Height="200" Width="200"  ManipulationMode="All" AllowDrop="True" DragOver="Shape1_DragOver" DragEnter="Shape2_DragEnter"  Drop="Shape1_Drop"/>
    <Ellipse Name="Shape2" Height="209" Width="209" Stroke="SteelBlue" StrokeThickness="5" AllowDrop="True" Canvas.Left="594" Canvas.Top="96"  />
</Canvas>
```

I've tried every combination of the DragOver, DragEnter, Drop events on Shape1 and Shape2 but they never seem to fire.  Do these events not work with shapes?  Or is it possibly that they don't work when using ManipulationDelta for the movement?

Thanks, I really appreciate any help or direction on this.

Comment: Is there an AllowDrop Property in Windows8? If so you should set it to true to get mentioned events.

Comment: Yes.  In the above sample I actually set it for both shapes, and at one point I even had it on the Canvas itself.

Comment: Does this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863492.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to get the bounds of your canvas, the size of your shape and its X,Y.  From that you can derive the 4 points around it (topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight).  When a point exceeds your boundary in the manipulationdelta event set it instead to that boundary.   This effectively keeps the shape "in bounds".

```
translation.X = e.Delta.Translation.X;
translation.Y = e.Delta.Translation.Y

// Since we are checking the left point subtract your shapes width from the canvas right
// bounds.  If X is greater than this set it instead to that maximum bound.
if (translation.X > (canvasright - shape.Width))
    translation.X = canvasright - shape.Width;

/// Same for top.  If Y is less than the canvas top set it instead right at the boundary.
if (translation.Y < canvastop)
    translation.Y = canvastop;

// Do the same for bottom and left
```

It is also possible to do this using the shapes center which may provide advantages depending on what functionality you implement.  When using center your calculation top or bottom of the shape is half of the height, left and right are half of its width.